# Window form open click event

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

Here I am using an 3d object designing product if I double click an entity a form will open, in some of cases clients are clicked multiple times before form open so double click event was triggered multiple times here it is running on thread,
I checked a condition if particular form is open then I neglect the form once again registering, but in my case after the form is closed next click event is triggered and form is opened once again like this after closing forms again it is opened, this continues several times

Anyone give suggestions how can avoid form opening several times

Comment: You could use a boolean field that is set when a Form is first requested, then reset when that Form is closed. A *manager* class that handles these events and implements a similar custom logic may be useful. It's commonly used, for example, with the async/await pattern, when you don't want a Control to trigger the same async code more than once before the async method returns.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to implement a Boolean system in your task, if you know what I mean. For example, when you form/application opens you can have a variable:

```
boolean firstTime = false;
```

When opening trigerring the double click event set the next form to this:

```
this.firstTime = true;
```

Then when the other forms open just put this code inside them to prevent them from opening multiple times:

```
if (this.firstTime == true) {
    this.Close;
}
```

When you are exiting the form just set firstTime to false, like this:

```
this.firstTime = false;
```

What would be better if you want your app to close and then have the same values is to store the firstTime variable in a locally stored file or in the properties of your application. If I didn't understand something correctly please inform me. Hope it helps!